# how to read this simple json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json (from file Php):

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "91",
            "cell": [
                "91",
                "Europe",
                "England",
                "Mark",
                "London",
                "blablabla"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I must read it by jquery. I use this code incomplete:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'test.php',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: data,
  success: function(response){      
       var obj = JSON.parse(response);
       ?????
  }
});
```

Example output:

```
State: Europe
Name : Mark
City: London
Note: Blablabla
```

Json return always only row.
I have found many examples but the format that I use is very different.

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would any object:

```
obj.rows
obj.rows[0].id
obj.rows[0].cell
obj.rows[0].cell[0]
//etc.
```

Obviously you should create a variable for any values you use more than once, but for clarity's sake, I've excluded that here.

Comment: thanks.. it works perfectly, but only after modification datatype from json to html.
if i use json I get error in json.parse

Comment: @user3361865 If you want datatype as json, you'll have remove `var obj = JSON.parse(response);` this line since the response is already a json object

Answer (score 0):

You access elements in array by index. In your response `Rows` and `cell` are `Arrays`.

```
For state = `json_response.rows[0].cell[1]` //Index of state is 1 in `cell`
City: `json_response.rows[0].cell[4]`
```

Note: If it always returns one row you can limit our response just to

```
    {
        "id": "91",
        "cell": [
            "91",
            "Europe",
            "England",
            "Mark",
            "London",
            "blablabla"
        ]
    }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6SjYP/)